# VB.NET support for ASP.NET 5 (MVC6)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-core

I've [heard rummors](https://twitter.com/DanielSchniepp/status/521591361267826688) that ASP.NET 5 does not support VB.net. Is this correct? Or does this apply only on some particular scenarios?

Comment: [https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/236](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/236): "ASP.NET 5 is C# only at this point and that will not change before we RTM"

Comment: I amended my answer to indicate the recent announcement that VB *will* be supported in ASP.NET 5.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update 5/1/2015**

On April 23rd, the ASP.NET team announced that support for Visual Basic will be coming to ASP.NET 5.

More information is on the .NET Web Development and Tools Blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/04/23/making-it-better-asp-net-with-visual-basic-14.aspx

---

**Original Answer**

Though it was mentioned in a comment, it's worth having a full answer.

There are no plans to support VB in ASP.NET 5 in terms of compilation, project templates, and other tools. This is discussed in the following GitHub issue on the ASP.NET 5 project: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/236

As that issues also mentions, ASP.NET 5 has some in-progress support to enable non-C# compilers to be used, but there is still no official plans to support VB (you'd have to roll your own).

Comment: if this will become reality, will there be any automatic migration tool inside Visual Studio, to FINALLY allow full VB.NET project migration to C# ? I'm waiting for this day to come.

Comment: that would be a killer app extension for VS2015 and would make a lot of developers happy.

Answer (score 6):

"We are excited today to announce that ASP.NET 5 will have full support with Visual Basic (both tooling and runtime – including cross platform runtime support).  As always, we will continue this development of ASP.NET 5 in the open, and you can track our progress or even contribute on GitHub at http://github.com/aspnet/home."

Taken from:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/04/23/making-it-better-asp-net-with-visual-basic-14.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding You can still develop application using VB.NEt in Visual studio 2015,  but you will not get the benefits of ASP.NET 5 like cross platform etc.

This is my understanding. Official decelerations are yet to come.