# So am I out of luck with my VB.Net web app with ASP.Net 5?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a large VB.Net web app.  According to this page:

http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/02/24/top-10-changes-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6 (scroll to point 3)

VB will no longer be supported in ASP.Net 5.  Am I out of luck?  And doesn't this go against numerous Micrsosoft promises to never abandon VB.Net?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET support for ASP.NET 5 (MVC6)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28040944/vb-net-support-for-asp-net-5-mvc6)

Comment: From what I understand, they will add the ability to add different language as a package. So the app could be written in VB/F#/... But I don't have proof of that.

Answer (score 1):

You will still be able to develop and maintain your app in VB.Net.  You just won't be able to port it to ASP.Net 5 using VB.

Comment: That means I will be stuck on ASP.Net and have no upgrade path?